# Flutter app showing Error: Assertion failed

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I just downloaded a flutter app in which flutter doctor is all check but when I run flutter run command it shows there are 3 devices available chrome , edge , window
I have tried with all 3 and in all of the 3 same error showing.

is showing assertion failed and on the link which it generated nothing showing there. Is there any solution ?

```
The Flutter DevTools debugger and profiler on Edge is available at: http://127.0.0.1:9103?uri=http://127.0.0.1:62622/2TBAVmeipJA=
Error: Assertion failed:
file:///C:/Users/satya/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_web-1.6.4/lib/src/firebase_core_web.dart:273:11
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 266:49  throw_
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 29:3    assertFailed       
packages/firebase_core_web/src/firebase_core_web.dart 273:18                                                               initializeApp      
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 45:50            <fn>
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1653:54                                          runUnary
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 147:18                                    handleValue        
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 766:44                                    handleValueCallback
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 795:13
_propagateToListeners
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 566:5
[_completeWithValue]
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 639:7                                     callback
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11                              _microtaskLoop     
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5                               _startMicrotaskLoop
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 166:15
```

Comment: Run ```flutter doctor``` and share the isssue.

Comment: there are no issue in flutter doctor